# Technology / program selection for picture viewing software

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, database

I want to learn some Binux usage and/or programming skills and provide an easy to use browser based picture gallery on my local home network. My idea is to have a server machine, that is the Linux machine, and store all my photos in it at some file structure or database. Then I want to access and manage (CRUD = Create Read Update Delete) them from browser on a tablet machine or mobile phone, connected via WLAN to that server machine.

My need is for a program or technology which would be suitable for the purpose of easily show and manage that content.

1. **Is there ready program running on Linux to do that?**
2. **If I have to build this from pieces, which technologies are needed to provide the minimum requirements of CRUD ability?**

I remember I have seen some file providers that show links to files at browser, but how ready products/technologies there is available to build such a thing up to your home machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Coppermine Photo Gallery](http://coppermine-gallery.net/) is useful or can serve as a starting point:

> Coppermine is a multi-purpose fully-featured and integrated web picture gallery script written in PHP using GD or ImageMagick as image library with a MySQL backend.

If you want to do it yourself, shouldn't be very hard to do with PHP or a web framework using Python, Ruby etc... (Django, Ruby on Rails etc...).

Comment: I am Java oriented, so probably I'll start with something like [this tutorial](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Loading_images_from_a_remote_server).. or then I'll follow up some of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_gallery_software) options..

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Coppermine is also Piwigo. It has better usability in terms of using the UI from a tablet device.

More information about Piwigo:

http://www.piwigo.org/

Other requirements:

This worked at least with this combination: Apache 2.2 and php5-gd. Normal php did not work, the gd version is needed.